# Assembler / GAS / Linux x86_64 - error while reading a file

Tags: gnu-assembler

I am writing a simple program in assembler on Linux x86_64 (GAS syntax). I have to read a number that coded in binary system and saved in a text file. So, I have my text file "data.txt" (it's in the same directory as my source file) and below is the most important fragment of my code:

```
SYS_WRITE               = 4
EXIT_SUCCESS            = 0
SYS_READ                = 3
SYS_OPEN                = 5

.data
BIN_LEN = 24
.comm BIN, BIN_LEN
BIN: .space BIN_LEN, 0

.text
PATH: .ascii "data.txt\0"

.global _start
_start:

    mov $SYS_OPEN, %eax     # open
    mov $PATH, %ebx         # path
    mov $0, %ecx                # read only
    mov $0666, %edx            # mode
    int $0x80                   # call (open file)

    mov $SYS_READ, %eax     # reading
    mov $3, %ebx                # descriptor 
    mov $BIN, %ecx              # bufor
    mov $BIN_LEN, %edx          # bufor size
    int $0x80                   # call (read line from file)
```

After calling the second syscall, the `%eax` register should contain the number of read bytes.
In my file "data.txt" I have "10101", but when I debug my program with `gdb`, it shows that the is -11 in %eax, so there was some kind of an error. But I am sure that "10101" was loaded to the buffer (BIN), because when I want to display what the buffer has inside, there is properly written number from the file. I need the number of read bytes to the further algorithm. I have no idea why `%eax` contains error code instead of the number of bytes loaded to the buffer. I wonder if it may be connected with calling `syscall` with 32-bit registers, but in all other cases it works properly.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I entered your code and compiled it on my x64 running fedora 20 using the as and ld 32 bit options to assemble and link it, and it ran perfectly, placing 0x18 into the %eax reg after syscall.  If you solved the problem I would like to know what caused it and how you fixed it.

cheers